Create a topic in docker apache/kafka
I'm following this guide https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart to run kafka locally using docker. On step 2 I run
docker pull apache/kafka:3.7.0
docker run -p 9092:9092 apache/kafka:3.7.0

Then, on step 3, I login into the container using Docker Desktop and run
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

But get an error /bin/sh: bin/kafka-topics.sh: not found. What am I doing wrong. Or there is some error in the manual?

Did you try try to ls bin ? Does that folder actually exist? The Kafka scripts should be in /opt/kafka/bin, so what if you use the full path?

@OneCricketeer - yes, found sh file in /opt/kafka/bin , and successfully launched it with ./kafka-topics.sh. Thanks. If you want, feel free to post your comment as an answer, will accept it

I checked the source code of the Dockerfile, and the correct bin directory is /opt/kafka/bin
So you could either give the absolute path of the script, or do docker run -w /opt/kafka ... to set the working directory.
Ideally, those scripts would be on the PATH, as they are with other kafka images

what about with the apache/kafka-native image (GraalVM Based Native Apache Kafka Docker Image)?  no bin in /opt/kafka

@goofology True. Use an "init container"  on the side with the non native image
